# python cmd module return to prompt after catching exception

Tags: python, cmd

I have this code and I'm using python 3:

```
import cmd
class myShell(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_bad(self, arg):
        raise Exception('something bad happened')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sh = myShell()
    sh.cmdloop()
```

and I want to return to the shell-prompt after the exception was thrown. How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the code, the functions are called from Cmd.onecmd (even in loop).

You can simply override it:

```
def onecmd(self, line):
    try:
        return super().onecmd(line)
    except:
        # display error message
        return False # don't stop
```

The advantage is that you don't stop the command loop.

Answer (score 3):

well you could override the `cmdloop` to wrap the original `cmdLoop` call:

```
class myShell(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_bad(self, arg):
        raise Exception('something bad happened')
    def cmdLoop(self):
       try:
           cmd.Cmd.cmdLoop(self)
       except Exception as e:
           print("recovered from exception {}".format(e))
```

the wrap will let `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` pass.

Comment: doesn't seem to do the trick for me. maybe because I'm using python3. (even after changing `cmdLoop` to `cmdloop`)

Comment: @ErikAronesty that is a reply to "thengineer" I suppose. BTW typo with semicolon your comment should read `while True: super().cmdloop()` :)